# Android studio - Движение клавиатуры вместе с edittext

Tags: java, android, edittext

У меня есть `EditText` большой длины (около 100 строк), мне надо сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на нужную строку она двигалась так, чтобы она была видна при наборе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почитайте про [android:windowSoftInputMode](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#wsoft).
По идеи он как раз отвечает за подстройку интерфейса при появлении клавиатуры.

Comment: Спасибо) разобрался))